# What is the optimum way to store, update, and analyze integer data for 100+ attributes?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb

I need to store the count of all individual characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, spaces, punctuation marks, all symbols...) that occur in different texts which will be frequently changing.

I will need to update all counts and analyze all of the counts frequently.

Is one table with close to 100 integer columns (one for the count of each character) the most optimum way to store and retrieve this data?

Comment: As requested, *discussion on this question* has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29650/discussion-on-question-by-user1420902-what-is-the-optimum-way-to-store-update).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Assumed business rules

As I currently understand your specifications, the following assertions are of prime relevance:

- A `User` inscribes **zero-to-many** `Texts`.
- A `User` registers **zero-to-many** `Characters`.
- A `Character` is counted in **zero-to-many** `Sums`.
- A `Text` contextualizes **one-to-many** `Sums`.
- A `User` computes **zero-to-many** `Sums`.

## Logical data model

And then, from the above enumerated assertions, I have derived the [IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm) logical data model shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5G15.png).

[image: Fig. 1. Characters In Texts Preliminary Data Model]

As you can see, with this structure you could have a **series** of `Sums` related to a specific `Character` in the context of a particular `Text`. Instead of performing an UPDATE each time that a new `Sum` is computed, you just have to INSERT a new row, which would hold the exact point in time that such `Sum` was calculated.

In this way, you do not need to have a table with about 100 columns, instead, as stated in comments, I suggest using a `Character` table that stores each character occurrence in an individual row.

I have also added a `User` entity in order to depict a more complete scenario, since I assume that all the sums (or counts) are computed by a determined user, probably with the aid of an automatic method.

This structure allows you to analyze with ease the trends of the sums that a given `Character` presents in relation to a particular `Text` by comparing the set of values contained in the aforementioned `Sum` series.